# Check the stability of differential equation using fsolve

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I want to find the equilibrium point of a differential equation and check whether the equilibrium point is stable.

Here's a minimal working example

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

dim = 2
A = np.random.uniform(size = (dim,dim))
sol, infodict, ier, mesg = fsolve(lambda x: 1-np.dot(A,x),
        np.ones(dim), full_output = True)
```

To find whether the solution `sol` is stable all the eigenvalues of the Jacobian must have negative real part. However the Jacobian is not saved in the `infodict`, rather the QR decomposition is saved in the `infodict`.

How do I get the Jacoian back from the QR decomposition of `fsolve`?

All I could do was something like

```
eigenvalues = np.linalg.eigvals(infodict["fjac"])*infodict["r"][ind]
```

Where `ind` are the diagonal entries of `r`, however I doubt this is the best possible way.

Answer (score 2):

QR decomposition is cheap: it takes a fixed number, around `n**3`, of operations, compared to finding eigenvalues which is an iterative process. Indeed, one of eigenvalue-finding algorithms involves the *iteration* of QR decomposition. So, knowing the QR factors does not really bring you much closer to having eigenvalues. And the cost of reconstructing the matrix by multiplication (also less than `n**3` operations) is negligible compared to the cost of finding the eigenvalues.

The conclusion is that reconstructing the Jacobian by multiplication is the way to go here. What you are doing (finding the eigenvalues of Q factor alone?) is not correct. First, recover the R matrix from its given flat form using `np.triu_indices`; then multiply Q by R; then find the eigenvalues.

```
r = np.zeros((dim, dim))
r[np.triu_indices(dim)] = infodict["r"]
eigenvalues = np.linalg.eigvals(infodict["fjac"].dot(r))
```

Answer (score 1):

Need also to take transpose of `infodict["fjac"]` to get Q. Also I had a bug if I labeled the matrix as "r". I would also recommend directly checking the Jacobian So :

```
import numpy as np

matrixr=np.zeros((dim,dim))                    # dim= number of linear equations
matrixr[np.triu_indices(dim)]=infodict["r"]    # to unpack "r" into matrix
Jacobian=(infodict["fjac"].T).dot(matrixr)     # needs .T to get Q
eigenvalues=np.linalg.eigvals(Jacobian)
```